# reformat knockoutjs JSON

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of multi-selected options that have to be sent in a certain JSON format.  However, in Knockoutjs, I'm getting this with the  selected:

```
"UserGroups":["Group1","Group2"]"
```

But I'm needing it to instead be like this

```
"UserGroups" : ["UserGroupName" : "Group1", "UserGroupName : "Group2"]
```

Here's my viewModel:

```
 var viewModel = new UserModel([
{ id: ko.observable(""), 
firstName: ko.observable(""), 
lastName: ko.observable(""), 
UserGroupsListOptions: ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"], 
UserGroups: ko.observable("") }]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: UserGroups:[{"UserGroupName" : "Group1"}, {"UserGroupName : "Group2"}] which is an array of objects

Comment: Understood.  How then would I change this to an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start out by looking up the differences (and similarities) between javascript objects (`{ }`) and arrays (`[ ]`).

As commented, your desired format isn't valid javascript. You probably meant to create an array of objects.

You'll need a function that takes a string and returns an object:

```
var makeGroup = function(groupName) {
  return {
    userGroupName: groupName
  };
}
```

Since your `UserGroupName` strings are already in an array, you can use `map`, a method that's readily available in an array and can be used to transform the contents into a new array:

```
var UserGroupsListOptions = 
  ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"].map(makeGroup);
```

Further notes:

- In javascript, variables (that are not constructors) usually start with a lowercase character. This can also help indicate which is server-side data and which is transformed data.
- Your viewmodel is constructed with an array of quite complicated objects... You might want to create *another* viewmodel that helps you create the inner objects.